# Programmatically retrieve function header information

Tags: c#

I have a function GetMainWindowAE, which contains the header information as shown below.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the main window automation element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static AutomationElement GetMainWindowAE()
    {
        //Return automation element using window handle of that process
        return AutomationElement.FromHandle(AppContext.ActiveApplication.Process.MainWindowHandle);
    }
```

How can I programmatically get the data which is in header with comments using .net?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection to achieve this. The **MethodInfo** property of the method contains the XML comments associated with the method (AKA the header information).

See [this blog entry](http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=49) for more information and code example.